# Checking a directory continuously for new files

Tags: python, multithreading, directory

I need to write a program which continuously checks a directory for new files and does some processing whenever there a new file is added. Obviously I will probably need to use some threads but is there any convenient way or pointers that anyone can suggest for achieving this in python ? (FOr both linux and windows)

Comment: With Linux, you can use https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

Comment: Both Windows and Linux. But for windows will be more desireble for me at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Busy" polling is a waste of resources. There are a number of different, operating-system dependant APIs that allow this kind of monitoring.

Some of your choices (for Linux that is) include:

> python-inotifyx - simple Python binding to the Linux inotify
>
> python-pyinotify - simple Linux inotify Python bindings
>
> python-gamin - Python binding for the gamin client library